# expected identifier or '(' before '~' token

Tags: c, debugging, token, getopt, pagerank

I encountered a problem while working on a project. I know there are many simillar questions that are answered, but regarding this special one I could not find any help. I am getting the following error:

```
Compiling main.c
main.c:42:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '~' token
~
^
Makefile:47: recipe for target 'obj/main.o' failed
make: *** [obj/main.o] Error 1
```

EDIT: I deleted the last lines of the code, but the error still occures at the line after the last '}'.

The project is about the PageRank Algorithm, using options in the console for choosing what algorithm is wished to be used. I am trying to read or use the options in the command line, but the error stops me from even looking at the semantic of my program.

```
/*
* main.c
*
*Programmierung 2 - Projekt 2 (PageRank)
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>

#include "utils.h" //is existing in the Directory


int main (int argc, char *const *argv) {
    //initialize the random number generator
    rand_init();

    printf("You gave %d command line arguments%c\n", argc-1, argc==1 ? '.' : ':');
    int graph;
    int i = 1;
    char * h = "-h show this help. \n";
    char * p = "...";
    char * m = "...";
    char * r = "...";
    char * s = "...";
    while ((graph = getopt(argc, argv, "hmprs")) != -1) {

        switch (graph) {
            default : printf("make -h | -m | -p | -r | -s "); break;
            case 'h' : printf("%s %s %s %s %s"), h, m, p, r, s); break;
            //this-like outcommended code like the one above
            //and again 
            //and once more
            //and a final one
        }
    printf(" - %s\n", argv[i]);
    i++;
    }
exit(0);
}
```

One more thing: I encountered a problem regarding the lengh of the case 'h' : printf(), so I outcoded the text in multiple chars.
If you need more information about anything, ask me.

Comment: In Line 42 the first letter, wait a sec

Comment: Where is you line 42? Your posted code only have 32 lines.

Comment: check this line case 'h' : printf("%s %s %s %s %s"), h, m, p, r, s); break;its having extra bracket

Comment: I reopened the file and there are now more lines, i added them.

Comment: That question is a joke, right? If you do not see the error yourself. burn your compiler.

Comment: Normally, you get the semantics (aka concept: "what?") first then you do the syntax (implementation: "how").

Comment: @SteamyBanana did you try removing the extra bracket?

Comment: @aa1992 Yes, resulted in another error.

Comment: Fix the errors by removing the five ~ from the end?

Comment: @CoolGuy I deleted them, then the error occured in line 41:1, the line after the last '}'

Comment: @CoolGuy Compiling main.c
main.c:41:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '~' token
~
^
Makefile:47: recipe for target 'obj/main.o' failed
make: *** [obj/main.o] Error 1

Comment: The only problems I see are the extra bracket noticed by @aa1992 and you declaring p twice. But your error looks unusual. Try typing the program once again in a new file or something like that.

Comment: @CoolGuy where is p declared twice?

Comment: @SteamyBanana which bracket are you removing?post your printf line

Comment: @aa1992 I removed it like you told me and it told me that there were brackets missing, my line is:     case 'h' : printf("%s %s %s %s %s", h, m, p, r, s); break;

Comment: You have mismatched parentheses on the `case 'h'` line. You're missing a `}` at the end of your source file -- or at least what you've shown us. The code in your question **cannot** produce the error message you report. Include the **exact** copy-and-pasted source code and the **exact** copy-and-pasted error message in the question.

Comment: @SteamyBanana post your "utils.h" code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it now. My compiler (vim) added lines out of my sight. I used another editor and could delete the unnessecary code properly. Yes, was my bad all along. I am deeply sorry, it was a long day.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler reports an error on line 42, but the source in your question is only 33 lines and it contains no `~` character. You need to show us the entire source you're compiling.

But I have a good guess.

The error message shows a line with a `~` character in column 1 and nothing following it.  The vi (or vim) text editor uses `~` to mark lines on the screen that aren't part of the file. If you copy-and-paste a source file from a vi editor session, it's easy to copy too many lines and end up with an extra `~` at the end of your source file.

Edit the file, jump to the end, and delete that line.

Comment: I made that, now it is telling me it's on line 41:1

Comment: @SteamyBanana: Your joking, right? Did you even write anything of that code yourself? Just apply the proposesd rule iteratively.

Comment: @Olaf I am serious. I am trying fixing this for an hour now, in my timezone it's in the middle of the night I am exhausted... By the rule, do you mean the while-loop?

Comment: @Olaf I wrote everything by myself with the official c reference. Please tell me if it is that trivial: what causes the error? I still have no clue

Comment: Then:  **go to bed!!**  The problem will be there for you *in the morning,* after you've had a good night's sleep ... a nice cup of coffee ... maybe a brisk morning walk.  (Having done this crazy line of work professionally for more than 32 years now, I can say with certainty that you **must** know "when to turn the damned computer *off!!)"*  "It's only ones and zeros," after all.  *Keep that in mind!*